# Routing issue in Codeigniter 3.0.5 on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I have issue regarding URL in Codeigniter on server.

Actually, Site was working before shared hosting server like `http://example.com/login`

But after change server dedicated and integrate SSL, the site not working inner pages. Like `https://example.com/login` where got below issue:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

But home page open https://example.com It might some issue related rewrite or else. I tried using `.htaccess` also but nothing changed.

Site page is open using add /index.php in between like `https://example.com/index.php/login`

Any one have idea or trick to sortout it.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you don't have access to the `.htaccess` file and you aren't aware of that ? The simplest way to test if apache uses the .htaccess file, is to break it - type some words in the first line and try to access again - if you get an internal server error - atleast you know it accepts this file...

Comment: Yes, I sortout this issue through .htaccess